# Angularjs placeholder not showing when dynamically generate textbox

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am generating a dynamically text boxes using angularjs. I set a array in controller and repeating in view with ng-repeat. Here is controller code :-

```
this.total_options = [
        {text : 'form.options.Option1' , placeholder: 'Enter Option Here'},
        {text: 'form.options.Option2',  placeholder: 'Enter Option Here' }
    ];
```

Now in view i am repeating this options like :-

```
<li data-ng-repeat="option in mcssController.total_options">                
    <input required="required" type="text"  ng-model="option.text" class="option" placeholder="{{option.placeholder}}" />
</li>
```

But when page is rendered the textbox showing ng-model property 'form.options.optoin1' instead of placeholder('Enter Option Here'). How can i solve this problem ?

Comment: can u post whole HTML file ?

Comment: HTML view plz Gitesh

Comment: i think related content i posted already. related content does not have any relation about that topic. @levi

Comment: Place holder will only be displayed when the input field is not filled. But in your case, you are setting it with option.text

Answer (score 0):

See if you clear out the form, you should be able to see the placeholder!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<li data-ng-repeat="option in mcssController.total_options">                
    <input required="required" type="text" ng-init="model=$eval(option.text)"  ng-model="model" class="option" placeholder="{{option.placeholder}}" />
</li>
```

You want ngModel to bind to a model, not a property that represents a string.  Since you want to interpret the string as a model, you can use $scope.$eval. It should work if you use $scope.$eval in an ngInit expression, and then use result to bind to ngModel.

Comment: how can i access text box values in model. I want the form object on model. the model name generate like form.options.option so in model i can get all values by $scope.form. But its not work in this way. @pixelbits